# Aligning 2 images/adding space below one

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, figure-placement

I have this figure:

[image]

I want them to be at the same height i.e. their centers are at the same y coordinate. This is what I have:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{images/circle_equation}
    \hspace{2cm}
    \includegraphics[scale=6]{images/circle_sdf}
    \caption{An SDF can be either a mathematical expression or be approximated as a voxel grid.}
    \label{fg:SDFRepresentations}
\end{figure}
```

I have tried using vspace in different ways but it only moves the caption, not the equation image.

Comment: you can raise the 1st image with`\raisebox`, but why is the formula an  image?

Comment: raisebox is breaking the document :\ It;s because I wanted a big equaiton to do a side by side comparison of 2 representaitons of a math model one is analytic the other numeric

Comment: `raisebox is breaking the document ` you must have used it incorrectly  use `\raisebox{20pt}{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{images/circle_equation}}`"to do a side by side comparison of 2 representaitons of a math model " side by side ok, but why as an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth,valign=c]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth,valign=c]{example-image-duck-portrait}
\caption{title}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
$\sqrt{(p-c)^2}-R$
\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth,valign=c]{example-image-duck-portrait}
\caption{title}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\resizebox{!}{1cm}{$\sqrt{(p-c)^2}-R$}
\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth,valign=c]{example-image-duck-portrait}
\caption{title}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]